# SQL Timestamp Subtraction to get number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the code below instead of active age I need to do a calculation with Open_time and the current time.

In other words i need to do if current time minus open_time is between 0 and 30, or 31 and 60, or over 60.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND CloseTime-OpenTime = 0-30 THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev4_030,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND Active_Age='0-30' THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev5_030,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND Active_Age='31-60' THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev4_3160,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND Active_Age='31-60' THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev5_3160,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND Active_Age='60+' THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev4_60,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND Active_Age='60+' THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev5_60
    FROM dashboard.dbo.SmThings
    WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
    AND Severity IN(4,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx datediff..

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND datediff('day',getdate(), OpenTime) between 0 and 30 THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev4_030,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND datediff('day',getdate(), OpenTime between 0 and 30 THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev5_030,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND datediff('day',getdate(), OpenTime between 31 and 60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev4_3160,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND  datediff('day',getdate(), OpenTime between 31 and 30 THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev5_3160,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND  datediff('day',getdate(), OpenTime > 60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev4_60,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND  datediff('day',getdate(), OpenTime > 60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as crosby_sev5_60
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmThings
WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
  AND Severity IN(4,5)
```

Comment: Though this has a logic problem since you may have dates that fall into > 30  and < 31 which would not show up in counts  but your original post had that problem as well.  This might be able to be resolved via rounding the datediff but I didn't know if you wanted to round or truncate.

Comment: Hold on, Not close time but current time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL - Use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

the output will be

> DiffDate
>   61

Comment: How would I use the current date instead of 2008-08-05? Also i need it to be like 'AND DATEDIFF(day,'open_time', 'current_date') = 0-31 or 31-60 or 60 + '

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
WITH Assignments AS (
    SELECT
       Grp = Assignment + '_Sev' + Convert(varchar(11), Severity) + '_' + Label
    FROM
       dashboard.dbo.SmThings
       CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT Age = DateDiff(OpenTime, GetDate())
       ) A
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT '030', 0, 30, '030'
          UNION ALL SELECT '3160', 31, 59 -- notice 59 here!
          UNION ALL SELECT '60', 60, 2147483647
       ) X (Label, Low, High)
          ON A.Age BETWEEN X.Low AND X.High
    WHERE Assignment IN ('Crosby')
    AND Severity IN (4, 5)
)
SELECT
   Grp,
   Value = Count(*)
INTO #Data
FROM
   Assignments
GROUP BY
   Grp
;
```

Then, you can automatically use those generated values to pivot (requires SQL Server 2005 or up):

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
SET @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM
   #Data 
   PIVOT (Max(Value) FOR Grp IN (' 
+ Stuff(
     (SELECT ', ' + Convert(nvarchar(max), QuoteName(Grp)) 
     FROM #Data FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
     1, 2, 0
  ) + ')) P
';

EXEC (@SQL);
```

Watch the magic happen! (Assuming I haven't made any mistakes, which is not very likely.)